# Eclipse MAT: Finding the variable name that's causing a leak

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-dump

I have a singleton object that contains a handful of ConcurrentHashMaps, one of which is causing a memory leak (i.e. it's taking up 99.5% of a 2GB heap).  Is there a way to determine the names of the variables for the different hash maps using Eclipse MAT (or another heap dump analysis tool)?  E.g. in this case the class is

```
class ABunchOfMaps {
    ConcurrentMap<Long, String> map1 = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    ConcurrentMap<Long, String> map2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    ConcurrentMap<Long, String> map3 = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
}
```

Is there a way to determine whether map1, map2, or map3 is causing the leak?  All I've been able to do is acquire the addresses for the maps, not their names.  I'm using the standalone eclipse memory analyzer, version 1.6.1.

Comment: Can't you just log the sizes in a separate scheduled thread ?

Comment: Did you check the "Leak suspect" page? This should display the root object. Are the classes compiled without debug infos?

Comment: @Konrad The leak suspect page tells me that ABunchOfMaps is the root object and that the leak is being caused by a ConcurrentHashMap, but it doesn't give the name of the map http://pasteboard.co/GJiAoZme4.png

Comment: There's no reason why it should be only one of the maps though. I really think a simple log line could help here. It's not really answering the question, but it would help investigating the issue

Comment: @Zim-Zam Did you check the details page? I see the members if I check heap dumps. You may remember the reference and check the details of the 'ABunchOfMaps' object instance. All members should be listed with the object reference.

Answer (score 2):

I know its very old thread . faced the same issue . Go to list objects--> By incoming reference , this will give you variable name